# Cassandra query getting error

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Friends I am getting this error when executing the following query : syntax error near unexpected token `('
Help me...

```
 INSERT INTO table_name(account_sid, transcription_id, audio_url, call_sid, callback_method, callback_url, cost, duration, recording_sid, status, transcription_change_date, transcription_date, transcription_sid, transcription_text, type) VALUES ('534534534534535', now(), '', '', '', '','', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type is a keyword in CQL, hence it is failing.
You can use double quotes to escape.

```
 INSERT INTO table_name(account_sid, transcription_id, audio_url, call_sid, callback_method, callback_url, cost, duration, recording_sid, status, transcription_change_date, transcription_date, transcription_sid, transcription_text, "type") VALUES ('534534534534535', now(), '', '', '', '','', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');
```

[List of keywords in CQL](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/keywords_r.html)